# Solution manual to Fetter & Walecka Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education, many-body, specific-reference

I am a senior physics major guy, I am trying to self-learn QFT and many body dynamics. I was doing okay till chapter 3. I am in need to a solution manual to see if I am getting the answers correctly or not. Where google has failed me you may help.

Any ideas where I can find the solution manual, or at least some tips/hints would be nice.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution book for the problems of the Fetter and Walecka.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because spec. ref. qs. are only for references known to exist.